# Can we use both stored procedure and Dataset in same Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in VS 2010. I have two sub reports. In the first sub report I have to use  a stored procedure and in another sub report I have to use a Dataset.

I know to use either Dataset or procedure but not both.

In the case of the Dataset when we set

```
CrystalReport rpt=new CrystalReport();
```

a new report document is created as a result the procedure is deleted

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardly doubt it is possible ,you can use either stored procedure or Dataset but not both